# How can I remove the second comma in each row of a csv file using sed?

Tags: bash, sed, csv

I have a bunch of csv files in a directory, and I want to remove from each row the second comma. Example:

Input:

```
53,900,1001,-45.4247,9.87187,541.65
75,900,0102,37.0896,4.24087,558.35
75,900,1101,37.3096,4.25814,561.65
46,901,0003,-51.3833,-20.2645,578.35
3,901,0003,-57.302,-23.0063,578.35
```

Desired Output:

```
53,9001001,-45.4247,9.87187,541.65
75,9000102,37.0896,4.24087,558.35
75,9001101,37.3096,4.25814,561.65
46,9010003,-51.3833,-20.2645,578.35
3,9010003,-57.302,-23.0063,578.35
```

Is this possible with sed?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

This way :

```
sed 's/,//2' file.csv
```

This option is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) as a flags avaible to the `s` command.

> number
>
> Only replace the numberth match of the regexp.

Comment: It is even a POSIX feature of `sed`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$2=$2$3;$3="";gsub(/,,/,",",$0);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
53,9001001,-45.4247,9.87187,541.65
75,9000102,37.0896,4.24087,558.35
75,9001101,37.3096,4.25814,561.65
46,9010003,-51.3833,-20.2645,578.35
3,9010003,-57.302,-23.0063,578.35
```

Comment: Please don't overcomplicate things. The op asked for a `sed` solution which was provided.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami while I'm no fan of overcomplicating things, we have had a few discussions on Meta ([one](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1172/117549), [two](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5409/117549), [three](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5764/117549)) indicating general support for answering using alternative tools.

Comment: `gsub(/,,/,",",$0)` would remove every non-contiguous pair of empty fields, not just the one you want. You have a habit of using `gsub()` when you should be using `sub()` in your answers. You also don't need the `,$0` arg as that's the default.

Answer (score 0):

The  gensub function from GNU awk cam also be used in this scenario:

```
$ gawk '{$0=gensub(/,/,"",2)}1' file
```